# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 2 (char 3)

Tags: python, json

I know this Question is already answered, but I dont know where the Error is in my Case.

This is my Code:

```
import json

json_data = """
{
    'position1': '516, 440',
    'position2': '971, 443',
    'position3': '1186, 439',
    'position4': '1402, 441',
    'position5': '1630, 449',
    'position6': '299, 681',
    'position7': '518, 684',
    'position8': '736, 691',
    'position9': '739, 431'
}
"""
data = json.loads(json_data)
print(data)
```

Im not really into working with json files, so please don't blame me if it's a really dump mistake.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear - what don’t you understand about it?

Comment: '516, 440',  the problem is the comma in the middle of the numbers is being interpreted the same as the comma at the end of the key:value pair, so you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes if you want commas in your values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use triple quotes `"""`. Instead use a dictionary with `json.dumps()` so that commas in your values are not misinterpreted as commas between items.

```
import json

json_data = {
    'position1': '516, 440',
    'position2': '971, 443',
    'position3': '1186, 439',
    'position4': '1402, 441',
    'position5': '1630, 449',
    'position6': '299, 681',
    'position7': '518, 684',
    'position8': '736, 691',
    'position9': '739, 431'
}

data = json.dumps(json_data)
print(data)
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using triple quotes, this would work

```
json_data = json_data.replace("'", '"')

data = json.loads(json_data)
print(data)
```

Comment: I was using this and worked fine until I had a value containing a `'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import json

json_data = {
    'position1': '516, 440',
    'position2': '971, 443',
    'position3': '1186, 439',
    'position4': '1402, 441',
    'position5': '1630, 449',
    'position6': '299, 681',
    'position7': '518, 684',
    'position8': '736, 691',
    'position9': '739, 431'
}

data = json.dumps(json_data)
print(data)
```

Comment: This is the exact same code as in my answer.